# How to .click() a button using WebKit in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, webkit

I'm running Xcode 8 and swift 3. I created a Cocoa app and imported WebKit. When I run my small app it opens web view browser and navigates to the website that I need. I can "getElementById", but how do I invoke clicking on a link?

my goal is to have a little automated test app on my website.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for anyone who stumbles upon it you can use `webKit.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('ID OF DESIRED ELEMENT HERE').click();")`